# How to get sheet index or sheet id from CTCalcCell Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to CalculationChain to get all CTCalcCells but I'm facing an issue where I'm not sure which attribute from the CTCalcCell is referring to the related sheet. Is it possible to get the sheet index or sheet id from CTCalcCell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Working with the calculation chain (Open XML SDK)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/working-with-the-calculation-chain) and [CalculationCell Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.calculationcell?view=openxml-2.8.1).

The attribute **i (Sheet Id)** is defined as a sheet Id of a sheet the cell belongs to. If this is omitted, it is assumed to be the same as the i value of the previous cell. So in `calcChain.xml` `<c r="C1" i="1"/>` refers cell `C1` in first sheet while `<c r="C1" i="2"/>` refers cell `C1` in second sheet.

Class `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCalcCell` has method `int getI()` to get that attribute.

It also has methods `boolean getA()`, `boolean getL()`, `java.lang.String getR()`, `boolean getS()`, `boolean getT()` to get the other attributes `a (Array)`, `l (New Dependency Level)`, `r (Cell Reference)`, `s (Child Chain)` and `t (New Thread)`.